# Tooltipster in Loop

Tags: tooltipster

I'm trying to use Tooltipster to show an image of hovered thumbnails that are in a loop. I've tried multiple ways to find the closest tooltip_templates class and show it, but am not having any success. Is there another way?

```
<li class="finish-swatch">
   <img class="tooltip" data-tooltip-content=".tooltip_content" src="/img01.jpg" />
   <div class="tooltip_templates">
      <span class="tooltip_content">
         <img class="tooltip-swatch" src="/img01.jpg" />
      </span>
   </div>
</li>

<li class="finish-swatch">
   <img class="tooltip" data-tooltip-content=".tooltip_content" src="/img02.jpg" />
   <div class="tooltip_templates">
      <span class="tooltip_content">
         <img class="tooltip-swatch" src="/img02.jpg" />
      </span>
  </div>
</li>
```

Comment: Do you want the same tooltip to be displayed for your images? Or how does tooltipster know what text to display? In my code, I have different tooltipster classes for each row or column in the table. But my html is generated by java code via Apache Tapestry, maybe that works differently.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the docs](http://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/) (5. Use HTML inside your tooltips)
This should work:

```
<li class="finish-swatch tooltip" data-tooltip-content="#tooltip_content_1"></li>
<li class="finish-swatch tooltip" data-tooltip-content="#tooltip_content_2"></li>

<div class="tooltip_templates">
    <li id="tooltip_content_1">
        <img class="tooltip-swatch" src="/img01.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li id="tooltip_content_2">
        <img class="tooltip-swatch" src="/img02.jpg" />
    </li>
</div>
```

Note: it is not recommended to use the class 'tooltip' as it may conflict with Bootstrap or other styles but I left it as you had it.

Also, make sure your CSS includes:

```
.tooltip_templates { display: none; }
```

Finally, your jQuery should include:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.tooltip').tooltipster();
});
```

That should do it. Let me know if you have any questions!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Jay. I also got this to work a couple of days ago. This is how I did it.

```
<div class="tooltip">
  <span class="tooltip_content">
    <img src="<?php echo $finish_image['value']; ?>" />
    <p><?php echo $finish_name['value']; ?></p>
  </span>

  <img src="<?php echo $finish_image['value']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt'] ?>" />
</div>

jQuery('.tooltip').tooltipster({
    trigger: 'custom',
    triggerOpen: {
        mouseenter: true,
        touchstart: true
    },
    triggerClose: {
        mouseleave: true,
        tap: true
    },
    side: ['top'],
    maxWidth: 200,
    theme: ['tooltipster-shadow', 'tooltipster-shadow-customized'],
    functionInit: function(instance, helper){
    var content =     jQuery(helper.origin).find('.tooltip_content').detach();
    instance.content(content);
}
});
```